# C# WCF Service is duplicating my data values in my List<>

Tags: c#, database, list

I have a problem, I made a service based on WFC in which I created a List based on values from a database. This is my code:

public List loadrGenera()
        {

```
        string dbStr = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Database2.mdb;");
        string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbStr;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Genera;", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        List<Genera> GeneraLis = new List<Genera>();
        Genera Generaob = new Genera();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Generaob.name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            Generaob.generaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["GeneraID"].ToString());

            GeneraLis.Add(Generaob);


        }

        return GeneraLis;
    }
```

well the problem is that when i call the service all the data in the List repeat, for example if i have

1-Fiction
2-Drama
3-Action

The method will return

3-Action
3-Action
3-Action

Always the last one repeated, I dont know what im doing wrong, can someone please explain me? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edit the same instance of Genera over and over again. You should instantiate an object within the loop:

```
    Genera Generaob;
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Generaob = new Genera()
        Generaob.name = dr["Name"].ToString();
        Generaob.generaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["GeneraID"].ToString());

        GeneraLis.Add(Generaob);
    }
```